# Firebase Database retrieve order

Tags: java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve pictures URLs from Firebase Database, ordering it by the most recent added to Firebase. I have this JSON model:

```
Pictures Data

 -KYXAJmJ678DCZ5lb7p0
 date: "20161209000235"
 downloadURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jam..."
 latitude: 26.46609249
 longitude:-101.98162083
 pictureID:"IMG_20161209_000232305.jpg"

 -KYXCHqx7j80MkYEF_B0
 date:"20161209001108"
 downloadURL:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jam..."
 latitude: 25.46614879
 longitude: -100.98159232
 pictureID: "IMG_20161209_001106058.jpg"
```

I want to know the Query to order it by the most recent object (using date parameter). I have this Query but it doesn't work.

```
mURLReference= mReference.child("Pictures Data");
Query mQuery = mURLReference.orderByKey();
```

I read that if we use *.orderByKey()* with no parameters it takes the first key in the object (so it must take date). But the order is still from first to last'. I want it from last to first.

If somebody could help me, I'd be in debt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `orderByKey()`, the items are order by their key. So in your case that is `-KYXAJmJ678DCZ5lb7p0` and `-KYXCHqx7j80MkYEF_B0`.

If you want to order by date, you should call `orderByChild("date")`.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but does exists a way to order it from recent date from the last date?

Comment: This has been covered before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+reverse+sort+order